# OSX, running instruments.app from console, how to?

Tags: macos, templates, instruments

all

I want to run `instruments` from console, here is the usage output:

```
usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
```

however I have no idea where the `template` file is or what should I specify for the `-t` argument.

And what the other arguments consume? The man page is too short to help.

Need your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type in `"instruments -s"` at the command line and be prepared to be amazed.

(and I found the answer by typing in the always helpful UNIX manual command... or in this case, `"man instruments"`)

Comment: Thanks, `instruments -s` gives the answer saving me a lot to `locate` it out.